# Merging pandas columns into a new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe as follows

```
     earningspersharebasic earningsPerShareBasic
2019                 -0.19                   NaN
2018                   NaN                  4.00
2017                   NaN                  0.21
2016                  0.01                   NaN
```

how can I merge the two columns into one using pandas? The desired output is

**output**

```
     earningspersharebasic
2019                 -0.19
2018                  4.00
2017                  0.21
2016                  0.01
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for replace missing values to another column with drop second column:

```
df['earningspersharebasic'] = df['earningspersharebasic'].fillna(df.pop('earningsPerShareBasic'))
print (df)
      earningspersharebasic
2019                  -0.19
2018                   4.00
2017                   0.21
2016                   0.01
```

Or you can back filling missing values with select first column by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with `[[0]]` for one column DataFrame from first column:

```
df = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, [0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Filled the missing values with 0 and took the sum total of both the columns. You can also opt for the solution provided by @jezrael.